# |DataDirectory| Wrong Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, architecture

I'm working on some 3 tier architecture project.

I created 1 solution, with 3 different projects: DAL,BLL and Presentation.

The DAL Project App_Data folder contain my mdf file.
In one of my DAL classes, i'm using the following command to connect to my database:

```
Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.\\SQLExpress; Integrated Security =true; AttachDbFilename = |DataDirectory|\\" + dbName + "; User Instance =true;");
```

When i'm trying to run it, i see that the |DataDirectory| returns the path of my Presentation Project App_Data folder(which doesn't exist).

How can i change it to my DAL Project App_Data Folder?

Thanks!

Comment: If this is or will be more than a simple application, I would suggest creating the database in ssms. Otherwise you could leave it like this and let it copy the database to the presentation project's directory to keep the one in your library in it's initial state (empty) so you can use a fresh database for every other project that references your library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the physical path.

However, you probably shouldn't - I know that's not the answer you are looking for but consider what is going to happen when the application is deployed. You will presumably not be deploying the solution but only the compiled presentation project. In this case, it makes more sense to store the database in the presentation project's App_Data folder and leave the reference as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the database to your presentation projects App_Data folder?